# Remote Power Shell Remote Management Session

Tags: powershell

I know Know that Powershell allows a remote Managment Sessions using the **Enter-PSSession** command.

My Question is the domain user suppose to have a valid logon session on the target computer or having the privilege in the domain is enough?

Would this be logged with windows 4624 event and kind of login event is it?

Comment: Why not try it out and check the event log on the target PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSRemoting is only enabled by default on Windows Server 2008 and higher. You have to enable PSRemoting on workstations (Enable-PSRemoting -Force) manually or via GPO.

PSRemoting, at least to use all of it, requires the user be a local admin on the remote machine. How you make that happen, either via GP Preferences, adding ADSecurityGroup or manually adding the user is up to you.

There several PoSH commands that can be used remotely without using PSRemoting at all.

> Tip: Work Remotely with Windows PowerShell without using Remoting or
>   WinRM
>
> Some cmdlets have a –ComputerName parameter that lets you work with a
>   remote computer without using Windows PowerShell remoting. This means
>   you can use the cmdlet on any computer that is running Windows
>   PowerShell, even if the computer is not configured for Windows
>   PowerShell remoting.
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699046.aspx